# jQuery UI - Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

[Solved]
I write this script. Unfortunately, jQuery console throw:

> Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

I use jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.4.

```
 $(function() {
$("#player").on('click', 'img', function() {
    var zadanie = $( "input[name^='act']:checked:enabled" ).val();
    switch(zadanie){
        case '1':
        alert('fajowo jesteś uczciwy');
        break;
        case '2':
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        break;
    }
    });
});
```

Dialog in HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Wybór karty, która zostanie położona oficjalnie">
<p>Fajowy tekst.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to initialize the dialog before being able to open it:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $("#player").on('click', 'img', function() {
    ...
```

Here's a complete example: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

Answer (score 7):

Set it up first:

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

Try it yourself:
http://jsfiddle.net/x5w8r/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the open method before the Dialog Widget has been initialized for more information go here:  https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/