# JQuery pop up dialog can not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am using `jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js` for pop up dialog. This is my code

```
$("#button_id").on("click", function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
})
```

When i click on button in first time it's pup up dialog as normal but after dialog close. Than I click on it again, It's show message like this

```
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'  like in image.
```

[image: it's show this message errors and stop pop up any more]

How to resolve it.

Comment: Can we get a JSFiddle?

Comment: what you mean @WalturBuerk

Answer (score 0):

Please Initialze it before using

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    })
```

Please have a look at this link

[jQuery UI - Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677799/jquery-ui-error-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization-attemp)